# typescript json array hardcoding

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Hi everybody I'm trying to convert a jquery app to Ionic.
I used an array of json object to switch from a set of value to others on UI change event.
This is part of the table I used

```
var table = {};
    table['0']  = {stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84};
    table['1']  = {stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84};
    table['2']  = {stipendio:899.44,base:638.39,ivmg:261.05,f025:8.08,f2650:16.16,f5170:24.24,f71:32.32};
...
...
```

and then I used a selector to choose which one of the row to use:

```
selected = $("#seniority").val()
paramsToUse = table[selected];
```

So I could use paramsToUse as a json object to get the value I needed.

How can I get the same result with Typescript?

Comment: I think your code is also valid typescript code as long as your have imported `$`.

Comment: what you mean importing $?

Comment: ` import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: ok got it, I would like to find some nicer solution though

Comment: @aristotll avoid using that syntax. Instead, use `import $ = require('jquery');` or `import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: @aristotll the actual explanation is quite complicated and cannot be expressed in a comment. Basically the way typescript handles interop imports is fundamentally broken. They're planning to fix it but it will take a long long time

Comment: @aristotll see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16093 for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you wanted to know how to create an array instead of using the table (sudo-array) you did in your answer, but I'll also show you how to easily extend it with NgFor.

Your table looks like this:

```ts
var table = {};
table['0']  = {stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84};
table['1']  = {stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84};
table['2']  = {stipendio:899.44,base:638.39,ivmg:261.05,f025:8.08,f2650:16.16,f5170:24.24,f71:32.32};
```

In Typescript, the more optimal version would look more akin to this:

```
// let is better than var because scoping issues
let table = [
  // You can put objects directly into arrays, like this. It automatically assigns indexes
  // so if you need to manually assign them it will be more complicated.
  {stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84},
  {stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84},
  {stipendio:899.44,base:638.39,ivmg:261.05,f025:8.08,f2650:16.16,f5170:24.24,f71:32.32},
  // ...etc
];
```

If you are using it on a Component, though, I would assume you'd use `this.table` instead of `let table`, but I don't know the rest of your code.

Later, in your code, you can use the wonderful NgFor to use your select (taken from @akz92 's answer)

```ts
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Table</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tablePosition" (ngModelChange)="selectTable()">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let value of table; i = index" [value]="i">{{value.stipendio}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ionic's select](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select) to choose a table:

```
// On your .html file
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Table</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tablePosition" (ngModelChange)="selectTable()">
      <ion-option value="0">First</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="1">Second</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="2">Third</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-list>

// On your .ts file
private table: object[];
private paramsToUse: object;
private tablePosition: number;

private selectTable() {
  this.paramsToUse = table[this.tablePosition];
}
```

Assuming that your `table` could be an array of objects

Comment: It looks like an array, i.e. `['0']` and `['1']`, etc (wonder why he's not using `[val, val2, val3, ...]`). Otherwise he could have an array of keys to use with the object and use that in combination with `*ngFor`. Though, can `*ngFor` iterate by object keys as well?

Comment: thank you guys, but the question is not on the component to use. I can't find the way to translate the javascript array of json I posted up here into Typescript.

Comment: Hey @NikRubblers , all Javascript is good typescript, so you should be fine.
Another way to do it would be something like this: `myArray = [ val1, val2, val3 ]`, or in your case `table = [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`.

In Ionic, if you used something like that array, you could then use `*NgFor`. If you want more on that I can write up an answer.

Comment: whatever sintax I use in Typescript it gives me errors.
I need ad array of json {key:value,key:value,key:value,...} objects but I can't find the way to get it

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys thank you everybody.

I've got it working using

```
table = [
{stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84},
{stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84},
{stipendio:716.73,base:531.52,ivmg:185.21,f025:7.21,f2650:14.42,f5170:21.63,f71:28.84}
]
```

much easier than I thought.

Thank again everybody

Comment: Just so you know, this is also standard in Javascript as well, not just Typescript :)

Comment: yes this is! the syntax I used before wasn't though! ;)